# Stopping Raspberry Pi display sleep

Tags: hdmi, display

I'm using my raspberry pi displayed on a tv through HDMI. It boots up into the terminal and is fine, however, when I leave it for a few minutes, the display goes to sleep.

I'm using an application called conspy to control the console from another computer, but the display does not wake once I start typing (I can still ssh and everything else).

Is there a command that will wake the display or just prevent it from sleeping? I'm not using the GUI, just the console it boots into.

Edit: I sometimes use the standard video output as well, so a fix for either hdmi or video will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure it's the Pi actually turning the TV blank, and not the TV's built-in sleep timer. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try

`you@yourpi:~$ setterm -powersave off -blank`

This should prevent the screen from sleeping for the current session. Put it in your `.bashrc` to make it permenant.

Comment: Returns "cannot (un)set powersave mode", even when I try sudo

Comment: Is X running? If so, end it and retry.

Comment: Or put this in your rc.local (then reboot): `sh -c 'setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0 < /dev/console > /dev/console 2>&1'`

Comment: Even better, add `consoleblank=0` to the kernel command-line.

Comment: I rebooted and it accepted it (setterm -powersave off -blank). My screen saver hasn't activated since.  Thank you.

Comment: I get an error: `setterm: terminal xterm-256color does not support --blank
setterm: cannot (un)set powersave mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device` :(

Comment: I think you forgot a 0 after blank.  (setterm -powersave off -blank 0) Is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=122112), you can edit `/boot/cmdline.txt`, appending `consoleblank=0`.

This changes the kernel parameter. (This is also mentioned in the comments to the other answer, but these are explicit instructions on how to set it.)