# How to Wake the Raspbery Pi Display Without Disabling The Screensaver

Tags: debian, display, xorg

People have asked how to [disable the screen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/disable-screen-blanking-in-x-windows-on-raspbian) from [going blank](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/752/how-do-i-prevent-the-screen-from-going-blank) or [to sleep](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/stopping-raspberry-pi-display-sleep), but I have a slightly different question.  I would like to be able to remotely wake a sleeping or blank display, but then allow it to go blank again.  So far this isn't working.

I've set `export DISPLAY=:0` in my .bashrc file and, when the screen goes blank, I run `xset s reset` over SSH.  What I've noticed is that the screen "wakes up", but that it will never go blank again.  I'd like to re-enable the default behavior after calling the reset command.  Should I just set up the timeout again or is there a different way I should be waking the display?  I'm just curious why reset changes the behavior.

Comment: Can't you just simulate a key press?

Comment: Any advice on how I would do that?

Comment: Default raspbian that I have doesn't seem to have `xset` any other options, or do I need to apt-get it?

Answer (score 9):

You have to define which display to use first :

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xset s reset
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there a reason I can't use those two lines in a shell script? When running only those two lines, I get: ["set:  unable to open display ":0]

Comment: The bash one liner: `DISPLAY=:0 xset s reset`

Answer (score 4):

That's happening because your monitor turns off after 10 minutes as well by default. And even if you reset by `xset s reset`, screensaver won't be effective as it assumes that your monitor is already off. You can confirm this behaviour by `xset q`

So solution ? : here : `xset s reset && xset dpms force on`

This should work effectively.

For more information (and detailed), read `xset` man entry. `man xset` and [this](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xset.1.html).

This is probably a very old question (2 years old), but I was trying to achieve the same and stumbled across this. I thought of contributing what I found.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @GrandAdmiral - I just confirmed this on my Pi 3 today. This is the best answer. Keep in mind too what Steven Luong C said: use "export DISPLAY=:0"

Answer (score 3):

From the man page:

> The 'on/off' flags simply turn the screen saver functions on or off. The 'activate' flag forces activation of screen saver even if the screen saver had been turned off. The 'reset' flag forces deactivation of screen saver if it is active.

So reset means deactivate, not reset to default.

Comment: Right, I understand that 'reset' deactivates the screen saver.  The problem is that the screen saver never re-activates again.  For example: 1. Startx 2. Wait ten minutes and screen saver activates 3. Run 'xset s reset' and screen saver deactivates 4. Wait ten minutes or more  5.  Screen saver does not re-activate.  I would like to get back to the default behavior of activating the screen saver after running 'xset s reset'.

Comment: `xset s reset && xset s activate`?

Comment: `xset s activate` immediately activates the screen saver without any delay.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of dhruvvyas90 works:

```
xset s reset && xset dpms force on
```

but this shorter version also seems to work fine:

```
xset dpms force on
```