# Wake console screen with SSH

Tags: ssh, screen, screen-saver

Avoiding installing anything or rebooting, how can I "wake" the TTY1 display via SSH?  None of the suggestions ([Stopping Raspberry Pi display sleep](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/stopping-raspberry-pi-display-sleep)) worked on my running Pi.

From what I have read trying to get an answer, these would work if I rebooted, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid a reboot ?

Comment: A wanted the solution available in my mental toolbox, instead of having to set up an install programs/settings in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So after a lot of googling I found the codes that setterm *should* be sending to the tty and these two command unblank the screen every time.

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/tty1
echo -ne "\033[9;0]" >/dev/tty1
```

The only reason I can think of all the other commands (that should have worked) failing was because the Pi is connected via svideo to a tv and not HDMI or a monitor.

Comment: Holy shoot, this also works for my nvidia blank console situation, that seemed impossible to revive

Comment: didn't work for Raspberry 2 B Raspbian on HDMI

Comment: You do not need to use `sudo chmod` to change the permissions on the tty device, nor should you do this.

The correct code should be:
`sudo bash -c 'echo -ne "\033[9;0]" > /dev/tty1'`

Comment: Worked for me with old Raspberry Pi B ver. 2

Answer (score 5):

http://www.winds.org/pub/grdl/ANSI.txt

ESC[9;#] is to set the timeout for screen blanking.  If you want to leave the timeout value alone, then use ESC[13] to unblank a screen.

So, depending on your shell (I use tcsh) a simple echo would be

**echo -n "\e[13]" > /dev/tty1**

Using the above example

**echo -ne "\033[13]" > /dev/tty1**

I saw no need to **chmod 666 /dev/tty1** first.  But I run as root (because I trust my abilities).

Answer (score 2):

I've probably answered this before, here or somewhere... but no worries...

Try:

```
setterm -blank poke
```

**should** unblank the screen from a login, BUT... usually you need to send the appropriate codes to /dev/tty1, not the /dev/pty/X you're using as an ssh user... thus:

```
setterm -blank poke | sudo tee /dev/tty1 > /dev/null
```

This sends setterm's output (magic codes!) to the proper terminal to wake it up as you desire.  Since I do this often, and use other options too, I made a little script I call '*tty1*'

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# send 'setterm' commands to /dev/tty1 (physical console)
setterm $* | sudo tee /dev/tty1 > /dev/null
```

Which I use like this:

```
tty1 -reset -cursor off
```

This command resets/clears the screen, returning to text mode and turns off the blinky cursor.  handy when I don't want the distraction.

```
tty1 -blank poke
```

Would wake up the screen.  (Well, **should**... works for me(tm))

(Do remember that you'll need to either set up nopasswd access to sudo, or be prepared to type the root password when you use this command)

*But wait! If you call now!  We'll include this gem:  How to remove the need to supply a password for sudo usage!  Operators are standing by!*

Add this line to a file named "*no-sudo-passwd-for-pi*" (no dots allowed!) in */etc/sudoers.d/*

```
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This will cause the user '*pi*' to not require a password for **ANY** sudo invocation. BEWARE! **This can be considered a security risk.**  Balance your need for this usage against the potential risks involved. (see *man sudoers*)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work even when run with sudo. I wonder if it matters that I am using the svideo out and not hdmi.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid a `chmod`, you can just use `sudo tee` to write to the console:

```
echo -ne "\033[9;0]" | sudo tee /dev/tty1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after exiting XBMC and going back to console screen: everything stayed black.

I solved this by calling once /usr/bin/xinit